# Failed to start native messaging host

Tags: native, google-nativeclient, chrome-native-messaging

I downloaded the native messaging example:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/

which I'm trying to run without any changes but i get a error :

> Failed to connect: Failed to start native messaging host.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in README.txt? Is python installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, i had installed python!